# How many ways can we give seven same candy to three children?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

> Question: How many ways can you give seven same candy to three children? (Every child should be given at least $1$ candy)

My solution:

$$\begin{cases}m+n+k=7 \\1≤m≤5 \\1≤n≤5 \\ 1≤k≤5 \end{cases}$$

> All possible solutions are:
>
> $115,124,133, 142, 151, 214, 223,231, 241,313,321, 331, 412, 421,511$
>
> So, we have $5+4+3+2+1=15$ different ways.

Is my solution correct?

But the answer I found is not in the possible answers. I can't see where I made a mistake.

Comment: The solution is correct, unless the children are also indistinguishable, and in that case the answer should be 4

Comment: @Exodd possible answers are: $10,21,27,36,42$

Comment: Your answer is correct, although there is a better way to do it.  Look for the stars-and-bars technique on Google.  The answer is $\displaystyle\binom{7-1}{3-1}=\binom{6}{2}=15$, as you calculated.  The book or wherever you got this problem is incorrect.

Comment: If you allow one or more children to get no candy, there are $21$ more solutions, for a total of $36$ solutions, and $36$ is one of the possible answers. Possibly the answers were originally intended for a slightly different problem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much!.

Comment: @Elementary: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Batominovski or, $5+4+3+2+1$ :) I used only algebra..Combinatorics sounds terrible to me :(. Thank you for checking and your fastest method .

Comment: @Elementary  Directly counting may work in small cases.  What would you do if there are $20$ pieces of candy and $6$ children?

Comment: @Batominovski Can I use The sum of a finite arithmetic progression formula?

Comment: @Elementary  I don't know which formula that is.  However, there are more than one ways to solve such problems.

Comment: @Batominovski so we have $ \binom{19}{5} $?

Comment: @Elementary  Yes.

Comment: @Batominovski thank you for this formula.I memorized.

Comment: @Elementary in doubt, 42 is always the correct answer